# Getting a Fatal error in Magento

Tags: admin

I am getting this error

**Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Marketplace_Helper_Data' not found in /home/ramrent/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 547**

Can you please let me know how can i fix this

Comment: please provide your conig.xml and adminhtml.xml for more detail

Answer (score 0):

**1)**

mostly this error come when you have use some extension helper class at somewhere and you remove or disable that extension and still that helper class code is in use by you or someone else.

**2)**
the helper node name is differ from you have provided in `config.xml` then you see this error

Other than this i dont think any issue would be there